# Expresion regular para coger 2 partes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A ver si podeis ayudarme por favor
Es para mod-rewrite en .htaccess

Partiendo de este nombre de pagina en una url:

> car-audi-tt-2

Necesito obetner toda la cadena completa

---

Pero si me pasan un guion seguido del año del modelo de coche Audi TT 2

> car-audi-tt-2-2019

Necesito obtener (con la misma expresion regular) esto: "car-audi-tt-2" en $1 y "2019" en $2.

---

Alguna idea?

Este es el codigo que tengo ahora y que hace match en el segundo caso solamente (probado en https://www.regextester.com):

> ([-A-Za-z0-9+.]+)-(20[-0-9]{2})*